# In MySQL how to calculate rate based on id and value column

Tags: mysql

For example I have a table MyTable like this:

> Id Value Rate
>
> 1  10
>
> 2  30
>
> 3  40
>
> 4  60
>
> 5  100

Rate is defined as: Rate = [ Value(id) - Value(5) ] / [ 5 - id ] , for id from 1 to 4.

I'm thinking of doing this:

> INSERT INTO MyTable (Id, Rate)
>
> SELECT Id,
>
> ```
> ??? real work goes here
> ```
>
> FROM MyTable
>
> LIMIT 4
>
> ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Rate=VALUES(Rate);

But can someone help me how to do the "rate" part? Thanks!

Another thing, if I define Id like this:

> Id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY

Is it possible the program could assign the value of Id not continuous, for example, the values of Id like this: 1, 2, 4, 5, 6? I'm asking because if this is possible, my program would fail because I assume the Id values are continuous.

In addition, is it possible the value of Id not starting from 1? For example, the values of Id like this: 2, 3, 4, 5, 6? I'm asking because if this is possible, my program would fail because I assume the Id value always starts from 1 and if there are five rows the last one would be 5.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: It's debatable, but in general cheaply calculated values need not be stored in the database.

Comment: I need to analyse the Rate based on Value, should I calculate Rate every time I need to analyse it? I thought it would be good if I save the Rate column for later use. If I'm not going to store it (Rate), how can I do the rate calculation anyways?

Comment: fair enough. sounds like a case where it wouldn't hurt to store it. disk space is relatively cheap

Comment: I'm not experienced with MySQL efficiency issue ... I will try your suggestion of not storing another column for Rate. Do you have any idea how to do the Rate calculation btw? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write:

```
UPDATE MyTable
   SET Rate =
         ( Value - (SELECT Value From (SELECT Value FROM MyTable WHERE id = 5) AS t) )
         / (5 - id)
 WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 4
;
```

Comment: Thanks. This should work! How about Id issue. If I define Id like this: Id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY. Will Id always be like: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5?

Comment: It will always be like 1,2,3,4,5 unless you have a database cluster (in which case you can get inconsistent ordering), or if you delete rows (in which case their IDs will *not* be reused), or if you set the `auto_increment_increment` server variable to a value other than `1`.